# Why jquery UI sortable don't work on AngularJS templateURL?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have sortable panels on each of my tab. If I put panels on index.html it works, but when used inside directive templateUrl: tabs.html it doesn't. Please see the Plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y3gOktwz6ViR1KRPUr0M)

My html file:

```
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <app-tabs></app-tabs>
  </div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $(".sortable").sortable();
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

My tabs.html file:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active:isSet(t.Id) }" ng-repeat=" t in myListOfTabs">
        <a href ng-click="setTab(t.Id)">{{t.Name}}</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active:isSet(1) }">
    <a href ng-click="setTab(1)">Add Tab</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-repeat=" t in myListOfTabs" ng-show="isSet(t.Id)">
    <div class="row sortable">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app.js file:

```
(function() {

  var modelTabs = [{
    Id: 2,
    Name: "Tab 1",
    Layout: 1
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Name: "Tab 2",
    Layout: 1
  }, {
    Id: 4,
    Name: "Tab 3",
    Layout: 1
  }];


  var app = angular.module('appTest', []);


  app.controller('testCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.myListOfTabs = modelTabs;
  }]);


  app.directive("appTabs", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "tabs.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.tab = 2;

        $scope.isSet = function(checkTab) {
          return $scope.tab === checkTab;
        };

        $scope.setTab = function(activeTab) {
          $scope.tab = activeTab;
        };
      },
      controllerAs: "tab"
    };
  });

})();
```

Comment: Run your sortable code inside a directive. The elements don't exist at *`document.ready`* time

Comment: I have tried that, not working

Comment: Should work fine if placed in proper directive , show what you tried that didn't work

Comment: I have updated the plunker, it works but with the whole element, not the sortable classes only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a `sortable` directive

```
app.directive("sortable", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "C",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.sortable();
      }
    }
});
```

This assures that once the element exists, the plugin will be bound to it

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wGH1731Futk4Lu3YADIC?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Helpful Solution. Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109588/how-can-i-pass-an-angularjs-object-through-jquery-sortable?noredirect=1#comment87236942_50109588

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to select the `.sortable` elements and apply the `sortable` plugin to them.
Next issue is that the items inside that `ng-repeat` won't exist in the DOM at the time `link` runs for the parent directive. You can find a clear explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235669/angularjs-how-to-query-the-dom-when-directive-rendering-is-complete). For now the only solution is a timeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sortable', element).sortable();
}, 100);
```

Also `<div ng-repeat=" t in myListOfTabs" ng-show="isSet(t.Id)" class="row sortable">` so that the `.sortable` class is not inside another `<div>`.

[Here is the working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZdYOVHnAmsdDtVyjF3D?p=preview)

Comment: that's a rather fragile approach using a guess on rendering time

Comment: Well, of course it is and yes your solution is better :)