# Angularjs and the bootstrap-select plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I want to create an Angular directive to use the bootstrap-select plugin and specifically the option to use a `data-subtext` attribute on the `<option>` tag [*as shown here*](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/#data-subtext) which would require something like this :

**html markup**

```
<select>
    <option data-subtext="Mustard's yellow" >Mustard</option>
    <option data-subtext="Ketchup's red">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-subtext="I don't know about Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
$('select').selectpicker({showSubtext:true});
```

I think `ng-options` is out of the question since I have to add the `data-subtext` to each `<option>` tag (correct me if I'm wrong).

What I have so far is this :

**index.html**

```
<select ng-model="idCourse" class="form-control input-sm" data-live-search="true" select-picker>
    <option ng-repeat="c in cources" value="{{c.id}}" data-subtext="{{c.name}}">{{c.code}}</option>
</select>
```

**module.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.courses = [
      {id:1, code:'CS1607', name:'computer science beginner'},
      {id:2, code:'PH006', name:'Quantum physics'},
      {id:3, code:'CSB-9', name:'Machine Learning'}
      ];
  }])
  
  .directive('selectPicker', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link:function(scope, elem){
        elem.selectpicker({showSubtext:true});
      }
    };
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the select plugin is called before angular could fill it with the data, I've created a [***plunker***](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8Fwukiq5phb7Z9sTodE?p=preview) for the code. Thanks for the help.

#### EDIT

As mer10z_tech suggested, using `$timeout` solved the problem :

```
//omitted...
.directive('selectPicker', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link:function(scope, elem){
        $timeout(function() {
          elem.selectpicker({showSubtext:true});
        }, 0);
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: you need to transclude child elements in your directive. Check transclude docs.

Comment: I added the `transclude:true`to my directive, still no luck.

Comment: simply adding transclude:true will of course not work, you have to handle the transcluded elements, as i said check transclude docs/tutorials.

Comment: in your directive you can wrap the elem.selectpicker call in a timeout function: `$timeout(function() {elem.selectpicker({showSubtext:true});}, 0);` http://plnkr.co/edit/y60KQd

Comment: @mer10z_tech the code worked as expected with hardcoded cource list but when I started fetching the data from the server the select is empty again. Is there a way to listen for the promise's success event or something?

Comment: @snajahi, R u calling elem.selectpicker.refresh() to update the option list..? I have just implemented a ajax call using this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284263/refresh-bootstrap-scrollspy-after-angular-model-changes . I should warn you that mutliple select is getting hanged if the option list is huge

Comment: @saiki4116 care to share a plunker or maybe update http://plnkr.co/edit/vSfh9HwIIxvN4RGXhuvK?p=info  cuz I don't see how I would access the `elem` inside the controller where I perform the AJAX call. thanks in advance.

Comment: @snajahi, The code snippet you have shared is working, may be you should increase time out. I have edited yours for the ajax call, it is available at http://plnkr.co/edit/gk8N3MCzBxusvPwAPbyi?p=preview  hope it would be useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would bind your selectPicker plugin after angular compiles the view. Her is how to do that

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').selectpicker({showSubtext:true});
    });
}
```

It is equivalent of $(document).ready()

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, The select list is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post was made long time ago but I hope this solution will be helpful for others.

I got another solution to the issue related.

What I did was first load my data from back-end using angularjs and inside the `.success` after my validation I wrote the following code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').selectpicker("destroy"); 
    $('select').selectpicker("render"); 
});
```

I tried to do it without `angular.element(document).ready(function (){})` but nothing happend. I suppose the plugin's methods only works inside that function.