# Load some functions after successful render of custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive as shown below:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.directive('formProgress', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            headingfirst: "@",
            headinghighlight: "@",
            values: "=",
            numwords: "=",
            customcallback: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: 'partial-htmls/toolbox/form-progress.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            /* this is rendering before the template is rederred */
            /* but it should render after directive has rendered right? */
            console.dir(arguments);
            commonUtilities.navigateToForm(3);
        }
    };
});
```

I am trying to call a callback function after successful load of the custom directive.

I tried using `link` property as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11126336/1577396).

And even tried defining a `loadcallback` function in `$scope` object and call it in the custom directive:

```
$scope.loadcallback = function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
    commonUtilities.navigateToForm($state.current.formIndex);
}
```

and then in html:

```
<form-progress customcallback="loadcallback()">
</form-progress>
```

But this didn't work. I even tried the following in controller which isn't working either.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
    commonUtilities.navigateToForm($state.current.formIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the callback from the directive itself.
Just pass it to the controller of directive:

```
scope: {
   customcallback: "&"
},
controller: function(scope, elm, attrs){
    scope.customcallback();
}
```

Html:

```
<form-progress customcallback="loadcallback"></form-progress>
```

Comment: use '&' instead of '='

Comment: @ngLover I tried using `&` too. this still doesn't call on complete load of custom directive.

Comment: @Mr_Green: It _does_ call it on complete _load_ of the directive, but that's not the same as on _render_.

Comment: @Cerbrus ohh then I am actually looking to callback a function on complete render. pardon my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to meet your requirements.

```
angular.module("myApp")
.directive('formProgress', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            headingfirst: "@",
            headinghighlight: "@",
            values: "=",
            numwords: "=",
            customcallback: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: 'partial-htmls/toolbox/form-progress.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            /* this is rendering before the template is rederred */
            /* but it should render after directive has rendered right? */
            console.dir(arguments);
            commonUtilities.navigateToForm(3);
          elm.ready(function(){
            scope.customcallback();
          })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't call the function after rendering of the custom directive. (calls before)