# executing function after multiple angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
     angular.forEach(values1, function(value, key){
       $compile(value)($scope)
     });

     angular.forEach(values2, function(value, key){
       $compile(value)($scope)
     });
    foo()
```

I want to execute function foo() only after these two forEach complete.
any help. I am just a beginner.

Comment: Where is your `foo()` at the moment?

Comment: after these two for loop

Comment: So what's the issue? The `foo()` will execute after these two loops.

Comment: even I thought so

Comment: can you people check now

Comment: you probably have to use $time out between compiles check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589106/how-to-wait-till-the-end-of-compile-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I think that would work

```
 angular.forEach(values1, function(value, key){
   $compile(value)($scope)

      angular.forEach(values2, function(value, key){
          $compile(value)($scope)    
           foo()
      });
 });
```

Comment: this is not my intention. I want foo() to execute only once.