# How to pass focus to a new field as soon as it appears (angular 1.4)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following example a new field is added (by adding a blank row to $scope) when the last field loses focus if it is not empty. The problem is that the new field is not added to the DOM in time to receive focus.

Is there a way to detect when angular has finished appending new field to the DOM and then pass focus to it?

Please, **no "timer"** solutions; the time it takes to change DOM is unknown and I need this focus switch to happen as fast as possible. We can do better!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kornieff/Lw9d4se9/5)

HTML

```
<div ng-app='a' ng-controller='b'>
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-model="row.word" ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'blur'}">
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('a', []).controller('b', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{'word': ''}];

    $scope.$watch('rows', function (n, o) {
        var last = $scope.rows[$scope.rows.length - 1];

        last.word && $scope.rows.push({'word': ''});        
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: use a short timeout to call focus() after dom insertion is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a View-concern and so should be dealt with by using directives.

One way to do so, is to create a directive that grabs the focus when it's linked:

```
.directive("focus", function(){
  return {

    link: function(scope, element){
      element[0].focus();
    }

  }
});
```

and use it like so:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-repeat="row in rows" 
       ng-model="row.word"
       focus>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnDJpAOjnDRQwhV3jpbr?p=preview)**

Comment: I like the directive idea. Somehow I can't get it to work with scope watch. I guess I will need to try ng-blur directive instead of scope watch. The downside to that is running a query selector on all the fields every time new one is needed (it needs to handle huge number of input fields).

Comment: @kornieff, where / why do you need `$scope.$watch`?

Comment: I need to create new input when the last one loses focus. I watch scope for the last row to fill and then I add one more. I guess I can try to use ng-blur instead.

Comment: @kornieff, I'm not sure I understand. This directive doesn't (shouldn't) care *how* it is decided that a new row is created. Do it however you want (I did it with a button) - but the whole point is that there is separation of concerns

Comment: Tried ng-blur. It works when I trigger it with clicking, but not when I press tab key. http://jsfiddle.net/kornieff/Lw9d4se9/2/

Comment: @kornieff, yeah, why would it.... but this is a completely separate question - that is, "how can I add invoke a function in the controller in response to a tab press on the input". So, it's best to ask a new question

Comment: Good point. It is "why focus via click is not the same as focus via tab?"

Comment: @kornieff, because it's not "focus via click" - it's "focus via calling a controller function that generates a row in the model, which because it is `ng-repeat`-ed, creates another input that then is focused". It may sound like a subtle difference, but it's an important one to internalize - that the controller modifies the model, and the directives deal with the View - a separation of concerns that the answer you accepted completely neglects

Answer (score 2):

Use `$timeout` without specifying a number of milliseconds. It will, by default, run after the DOM loads, as mentioned in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive) question.

```js
angular.module('a', []).controller('b', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.rows = [{
    'word': ''
  }];

  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({
      'word': ''
    });
    $timeout(function() {
      //DOM has finished rendering
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
      inputs[inputs.length - 1].focus();
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='a' ng-controller='b'>
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <input type="text" ng-model="row.word" ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'blur'}"><br>
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-click="addRow()" value="Add Row">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did not work when I tried in jsfiddle. (Tested in FF and Cr)

Comment: `autofocus` is for when the page loads, not just whenever.

Comment: There was never anything getting added in the fiddle, so I just thought it needed to happen on page load. Updated with more appropriate answer.

Comment: @AndrewMairose, thanks for explaining $timeout workaround. Definitely +1. Is there a less hacky way of doing it? Something like $renderComplete.

Comment: What if in the View, the "row" is really inside a template - `<div ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-include="'/templates/row.html'">`? This approach fails immediately. Not to mention that a controller should be DOM-agnostic