# Execute a function once HTML is rendered after web service call - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to execute a piece of code once view is completely rendered.

1. Click on button, web service will be called
2. Once response is received, lot of data will get rendered on ng-repeat
3. After view is completely rendered, execute a piece of code

I know I can use callback once response is received but HTML rendering might take time. To avoid that I can also write my piece of code in $timeout function but that doesn't feel right approach to me. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use ng-if in your template to get it render after the result from RestAPI Call, then you will be able to execute your second set of code on success.

Comment: Okay. Now template will render only when response from service is received. Now after rendering, how to execute a function?
service call (Request) > Response received > Template Rendering > execute function. How to do last part?

Comment: Then you have the timeout function only as a solution as per this below link,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive

Comment: Anything without $timeout? Somehow I do not find this solution cleaner.