# Refresh page on route change without infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to refresh every new page that AngularJS loads as follows:

Controller:

```
angular.module('adsomaApp')
  .controller('BrandsController', function ($window) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.init = function() {
      $window.location.reload();
    };
  });
```

View

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BrandsController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">Test</div>
```

Strangely, this causes the page to reload indefinitely. It gets stuck in a loop. Any idea how I can get it to reload once on route change?

I think the cause of the problem is here:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name adsomaApp.directive:resize
 * @description
 * # resize
 */
angular.module('adsomaApp')
  .directive('resize', function () {
    return function (scope, $window) {
      var w = angular.element($window);

      scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return {
          'h': screen.height,
          'w': window.innerWidth
        };
      };

      scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue) {
        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
        scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

        scope.youtubeBgVideoStyle = function () {
          return {
            'max-width': '1000%', 
            'margin-left': '0px', 
            'width': newValue.w + 'px',
            'min-height': '100vh', 
            'height': newValue.h + 'px',
            'margin-bottom': '-50%'
          };
        };
      }, true);

      w.bind('resize', function () {
        scope.$apply();
      });

      w.bind('load', function () {
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
  });
```

How do I trigger this directive refresh on route change?

Comment: why are you refreshing pages ?

Comment: There’s an element on each page that doesn’t render correctly until the page is refreshed

Comment: @methuselah angularjs is an SPA, it's not meant to refresh. Wouldn't it be better to ask about why it doesn't render correctly? Also there is no strange behaviour in your example. You are calling `vm.init()` in your `ng-init` once the page is rendered after a refresh, which refreshes it in the function, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey is there a way around it? I think the cause of this error is this directive: https://pastebin.com/Ffmj7ars

Comment: @methuselah a **hack** would be to call a digest cycle instead. It is responsible for rendering any dynamic content (with watchers). That's why after any jQuery code (DOM manipulations), you would call `$scope.$apply()` to re-render the changes. So you may want to call that or `$scope.$digest()`. [Here is more about their difference](http://www.jstips.co/en/angular/angularjs-digest-vs-apply/)

Comment: Ah I see, then how would I trigger this digest cycle on route change?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I've updated the question

Comment: @methuselah since it's a directive, it might be enough to [delay the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive) after the render with `$timeout`. Just wrap your relevant function with it

Comment: Did this, and it's not working: https://pastebin.com/Q6NpJ2Er. The changes aren't even applied on initial load

Comment: @methuselah now it's out of scope of the original question. I suggest asking a new question, explaining what you tried already. I'm not that familiar with directives, but `$timeout` **returns a Promise**, so I think `scope.youtubeBgVideoStyle = $timeout(...` syntax is wrong