# AngularJS - Listen for onclick events for all table <td>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cefsharp

Is there a way to use `angular.element(...).on('click', onTdClick);` (for example) in a way that executes onTdClick (providing the element to it) on every  that gets clicked?

Let's say I have 2 tables, both have cells and columns.
I want to be able to click on CELLS and send the  element of what I clicked and send it to `onTdClick($event)`.

```
$scope.onTdClick = function(ev){
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(ev.target);
};
```

Essentially doing the same as: `ng-click="onTdClick($event)"` without having to put ng-click on hundreds of `<td>`'s

I dynamically add table rows and table cells with .insertRow and .insertCell
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp
So statically doing `angular.element().find('td').on()` wont work well here.

#### Whats my end result?

I'm attempting to make it so I can click `<td>`'s to essentially highlight cells by just clicking them.
The highlight code is already tested and works:
`window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(ev.target);`
(where ev is the td element)

Comment: if you generate your table rows with `*ng-for`, you only need to write `ng-click` once.

Comment: why do you have hundred of `<td>`s ? can't you use an `ng-for`? ... of course you could use `angular.element(document).find('td')` to match all `td`s in your page

Comment: @JeremyThille I generate it via a callback on CEFSharp with insertRow().

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Yeah but wouldnt that not match td's added after that code was executed?

Comment: depends where you put this code - there should be some way to know when a comp has rendered - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive and similar questions

Comment: @OvidiuDolha What im looking for is essentially a way to just apply the ng-click="onTdClick($event)" globally on all <td>'s preferably without having to reference td's or not have to run a angular.element() code every time I insert a row.

Comment: I guess you could easily do that if you could somehow decide to use something else (e.g. your own comp/directive) instead of  `td` - is that possible somehow? e.g. use a template in `insertRow` <- whatever this is

Comment: @OvidiuDolha https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp thats insertRow. I dont think making a custom directive of <td> would work very well here.

Comment: Oh I see - well look at this: `Return Value: The inserted <tr> element` - couldn't you use the returned element? btw: I think it would be easier if you could add your code of how the table is constructed - it's difficult to speculate

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Its initially a blank table with just a table header, then at random times in code, I just insert rows with the page I linked above as an example usage case. So I cant exactly add ng-click to em or anything.

Comment: So if you mean you don't have access to change the actual code where `insertRow` is invoked, then I guess another approach (probably a bad one) is to hijack the `insertRow` function itself and overwrite it with your own to add the click event e.g. `const original = HTMLTableElement.insertRow; HTMLTableElement.insertRow = function() { const tr = original.apply(this, arguments); // add click event ... }`

Comment: @OvidiuDolha That would propably be a solution, but id then have to call that every time causing a bit of lag overtime. (It will be adding thousands of rows overtime). There's no way to just hook the click event of every <td>?

Comment: You only have to call that once before the first insertRaw is called

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use insertRow with AngularJS. Instead, you should use ng-repeat with an array that has an object for every row, and just push objects when you want to insert a row.

```
$scope.insertRow = function(){
    $scope.tdList.push({});//push whatever you want
}
```

If you want the number of cells to be variable, you can store some param in this object to tell the view how many cells the row has, and put a nested ng-repeat inside to create the cells

Comment: I specifically do insertRow for performance reasons. After time ill end up with thousands of rows, and having that go through all AngularJS's checks makes it extremely slow after time.

Comment: I see your point. But I still would suggest you to use some tricks to increase the performance of the ng-repeat, even you can do the ng-repeat static and only look for changes when you tell angular to do. I think it would be a lot easier for you.
 Take a look at this article, for example: http://www.codelord.net/2017/01/25/techniques-for-improving-ng-repeat-performance/

Comment: It still un-necessarily requires checking and such, whereas with insertRow, I just do it, Done. I wont be using ng-repeat.